# Resource-based RBAC implementation ideas

Tags: keycloak, auth0, okta, rbac

I have a need to implement a quite sophisticated RBAC model in my application.
It very much resembles Azure RBAC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview

Let me explain it on an example:

Say I have a resource type: `server_group`.

And then I have roles:

1. `admin` (can do `CRUD` on `server_group` + other permissions)
2. `editor` (can do `RU` on `server_group` + other permissions)
3. `viewer` (can only `R` `server_group` + other permissions)

Those roles are tenant-wide roles: the scope of operation here is the organization within which the current user is registered.

This is the traditional model of assigning permissions on roles for resource types.

But then, what if you have a need to grant more privileges to a certain user that has a role of a `viewer` but within a scope of a particular instance of a resource type?

Mark is an administrator, he has created a `server_group` `sg1` and he wants to assign a role of a `server_group_editor` to Alice, who has a `viewer` tenant-wide role.

The `server_group_editor` role has a scope of application: `server_group`.

`server_group_editor` adds the ability to update the `server_group` resource type.

Since Alice has the role of `server_group_editor` within the `sg1` instance, she now can edit this resource.

Previously she couldn’t do that as her tenant-wide permissions allowed her to only list all server groups.

I hope it makes sense.

That being said, I would love to know if there are products out there that support such a flexible RBAC model, be it either SaaS or applications that can be deployed as a standalone service?

I was looking at Auth0, Okta, KeyCloak, and I cannot see them supporting this model.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not an Azure-rbac issue, but an Auth0, Okta, KeyCloak rbac issue. I removed the Azure rbac tag.

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar kind of problem at the company I work for.

We use Auth0, but the built-in roles/permissions capability didn't quite meet our complex fine-grained authZ requirements - basically we needed to be able to deal with users that could be in one or more groups, but with different permissions in each group. We *could* have solved this by storing a complex permissions structure in `app_metadata` and then appending this to the user access token (via an Auth0 rule), but we anticipated this getting unwieldly...

We solved this by building an internal "entitlement" microservice and persisting some access control data on our side (i.e. users, groups, roles, & permissions).

Here's a high level diagram:
[image]

When a user signs-up (using Auth0 customized Universal Login page that talks to 'IdpFacade' microservice) we publish an event to message broker (Azure Service Bus). This event triggers the creation of the user in the 'access control' data store (as well as the initial group, role, permission associations). *Note: we can also update this data store via API (e.g. if we want to dynamically assign additional roles/permissions to a user)*.

When a user makes a request to an entitlements-enabled microservice, we defer fine-grained authZ decisioning to the entitlements service. The entitlement service first queries the users roles/permissions from the data store (based on the JWT subject, which is essentially the user identifier from Auth0/IDP). We then pass this information along with the HTTP method, URI / resource path, and (optional) additional metadata (in the form of key-value pairs) through to [Open Policy Agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/) (a.k.a. OPA) using the [Overload input](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/external-data/#option-2-overload-input) pattern. OPA defines all the authZ policies in a DSL called [Rego](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/) and does the decisioning.

The response from the 'entitlement' service is basically a single field that indicates whether access should be allowed or denied. The entitlements-enabled microservice would return a HTTP 403 if allow is false. FYI. we built a bit of boilerplate in .NET Core to simplify the call to entitlements. Here's an example:
[image]

```
[HttpPost]
[CheckEntitlement()]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync(
```

Note: in the attribute we can specify a policy name, as well as (optional) metadata.

Pros of this approach:

- Simplified IDP implementation
- Simplified authZ logic in microservices e.g. they don't need to know about complex authZ hierarchies/requirements, just call entitlements.
- Decoupled architecture - ability to update authZ policies without touching microservices.
- Real-time authZ i.e. can update roles/permissions and changes would be immediate, as opposed to permissions in JWT, which are valid until the JWT expires.

I should probably do a detailed blog about the approach, as I think it's a pretty nice approach (albeit a bit of work to set up initially).

Comment: How do you paginate the data granted that the user does have access to certain objects from the list? You need to pass down the ids of resources that he has been granted/denied access from the finer-grained assignments. 
Only then, the underlying micro-service will be able to properly filter out the data.

Comment: I think I understand your question. The entitlement service doesn't know about the owner of a particular resource, so we have to pass this through from the entitlement-enabled microservice (as metadata). The `CheckEntitlement` attribute can optionally define an `IMetadataProvider` impl e.g. `ResourceOwnerMetadataProvider` which might resolve the actual resource owner based on the resource defined in the URL path e.g. `/api/v1/transaction/{transaction-id}` and add this to the request. We have some complex user hierarchies to deal with so need to deal with things like inferred permissions...

Comment: Note: OPA does not have a database, so we need to pass everything through so it can make policy decisions.

Comment: The fact that you use OPA is secondary... my question was about the pagination. For example, say you have in your system an entity called "students". Without any authorization rules, GET /api/students?page=1, would return me first page with 20 items on it and a metadata containing a total count of `X`. Now the client of my API can properly paginate the data.
But if you have fine-grained RBAC, when some users could be denied access to all items by default and granted to a subset in a form of exclusion, how would you correctly paginate the data for the subject?

Comment: OPA or not OPA, I need to pass down into my micro-service, that is retrieving the data from the source of truth datastore, information about the items that user was granted/rejected access, and then apply some other filters that come from URL  request parameters. 
This whole ALLOW/DENY decision making works fine if you are deciding whether the subject has access to a single item, but when you are retrieving a list and you need to properly display the total counts, fetch properly page by page, this is where I see the complexity. 
Thanks for engaging btw, I appreciate it.

Comment: "OPA does not have a database", I am looking at the data API: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/rest-api/#data-api
And it seems like it is storing documents somewhere.

Comment: I think my scenario is a bit different to yours... anyways, when you call `/api/students` it sounds like you intend to return a list of students that the consumer is authorized to view... I'm not sure, but is this more part of your search/filter logic than authorization per se` - I can see that it's kinda related, but... I haven't hit this scenario (yet)... oh and you are right about OPA having a db, I more meant our (rego) policies don't query a db :)